# adding an email scope causes POSTs to oauth-authorize to throw 400 error on curity 6.0.0

Tags: openid, curity

[image]An HTTP POST to the :8443/oauth/v2/oauth-authorize?client_id=www where an email scope is provisioned throws a 400 error.

The email scope on line 13 causes the error:

```
<config xmlns="http://tail-f.com/ns/config/1.0">
  <profiles xmlns="https://curity.se/ns/conf/base">
  <profile>
    <id>token-service</id>
    <type xmlns:as="https://curity.se/ns/conf/profile/oauth">as:oauth-service</type>
      <settings>
      <authorization-server xmlns="https://curity.se/ns/conf/profile/oauth">
      <client-store>
      <config-backed>
      <client>
        <id>www</id>
        <secret>********************************************************************</secret>
        <redirect-uris>https://xx.xxxxx.xxx/openid-connect/generic</redirect-uris>
        <scope>email</scope>
        <scope>openid</scope>
        <claims-mapper>default</claims-mapper>
        <user-authentication>
          <allowed-authenticators>username-password</allowed-authenticators>
        </user-authentication>
        <capabilities>
          <code/>
        </capabilities>
        <use-pairwise-subject-identifiers>
          <sector-identifier>www</sector-identifier>
        </use-pairwise-subject-identifiers>
        <validate-port-on-loopback-interfaces>true</validate-port-on-loopback-interfaces>
      </client>
      </config-backed>
      </client-store>
      </authorization-server>
      </settings>
  </profile>
  </profiles>
</config>
```

The server logs contain:

```
2021-04-09T13:40:06:466+0000 WARN  LawmynV9 c2073b3a {req-203} se.curity.identityserver.claims.StandardClaimValuesResolver - One or more of the configured claims providers isn't licensed
2021-04-09T13:40:06:466+0000 WARN  LawmynV9 c2073b3a {req-203} se.curity.identityserver.tokens.scripting.TokenProcedure - Token procedure with ID _default-authorize-code threw an Exception: A license violation has occurred
2021-04-09T13:40:06:466+0000 INFO  LawmynV9 c2073b3a {req-203} se.curity.identityserver.controllers.InteractiveOAuthController - Unable to translate error thrown by procedure, responding with server error
```

I assume this is a feature that allows configuration but doesn't work in the community edition of Curity.

Comment: I don't feel SO is the correct site for these questions. Would https://serverfault.com/ not be a better venue for these questions?

Comment: In general, I think curity tagged questions could end up in 3 or 4 different Stack Exchange communities. Reading https://meta.serverfault.com/a/2604, it talks about a similar example for PHP. Hard for Stack Exchange noobs (or even non-noobs, I bet) to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The license enforcement happens on runtime, so the configuration service allows you to configure the claims provider here for example, but that claims provider is not allowed for Community license. That's why you get this error.

What type of claims-provider are you trying to use?

Comment: I'm tying to use Curity to provide authentication for Drupal 9 via its openid_connect generic client version 1.0. That client requires an email scope and after enabling the scope in Curity I only receive a 400 error with no detail. Frustrating after spending time to get this working.

Comment: Can you share your configuration for claims and claims-providers? You can go into the admin UI and click `view xml` and then copy paste it here ? It will help us identify why that feature is not allowed most likely

Comment: I have added the XML configuration option that leads to the issue. With the email scope added to the www client as it is otherwise defined in the getting started docs will respond with 400 on hitting the oath-authorize endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, we replicated and identified a bug which will be fixed in the next version. In the meantime, if you are blocked by this bug let us know so we can issue a temporary license to you which works around it.